# weird sigwait() behaviour and understand blocking and unblocking signals

Tags: c++, signals

Consider the next piece of code:

```
// Sigaction and timers
struct sigaction sa;

sigset_t maskSet, pendingSet;

/**
* Blocks the SIG_SETMASK in maskSet.
* @return None.
*/
static void block_signal(void)
{
    // ~~~Blocking signal~~~
    if(sigemptyset(&pendingSet) == -1)
    {
        ErrorHandler::sysCallError(THREAD_SYS_CALL_ERROR_SIGNAL_HANDLE);
    }
    if(sigpending(&pendingSet) == -1)
    {
        ErrorHandler::sysCallError(THREAD_SYS_CALL_ERROR_SIGNAL_HANDLE);
    }

    if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &maskSet, NULL) == -1)
    {
        killProcessAfterMemoryAllocs();
    }
}

/**
* Unblocks the SIG_SETMASK in maskSet.
* @return None.
*/
static void unblock_signal(void)
{
    // ~~~Blocking signal~~~

    int result;
    int sig;

    // If we got a signal while performing operation that require signal block.
    if(sigismember(&pendingSet, SIGVTALRM) != -1)
    {
        result = sigwait(&pendingSet, &sig);
        // DOESNT REACH HERE
        if(result == 0)
        {
            printf("sigwait() returned for signal %d\n", sig);
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &maskSet, NULL) == -1)
    {
        killProcessAfterMemoryAllocs();
    }
}
```

My main goal is to be able to run functions, that during their run - `SIGVTALARM` ,that is raised by a timer i defined, will be blocked. (block_signal -> dosomthing *SIGNALS ARE BLOCKED* -> unblocksignal). Maskset is initialized with `SIGVTALARM`

Two questions:

- By the way i implemented, `result = sigwait(&pendingSet, &sig);` causes the program go into an infinite loop.
- Without sigwait() - I use a virtual timer that raise SIGVTALARM every defined interval of time. 
  Suppose i blocked SIGVTALARM. I understand that, as soon (while blocked) as it is raised - the signal becomes pending.  And as soon as i unblock it, the signal is recieved and treated by a signal hanler.
  What i dont understand is whats going on with the NEXT signal raised. Will the next signal will be raised a defined interval of time after the PREVIOUS signal released, or will it be raised a defined interval of time from the moment the PREVIOUS signal raised (and blocked -> became pending).